# Onkeyup does not work on first fire

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have this code which checks the length of characters in a textbox on paste.

`<asp:TextBox id="fileDescriptionTxtbox" onKeyUp = "checkLength();"></asp:TextBox>`

My concern is, it does not work on first keyup event(first paste). It only works when I paste the same characters the second time.

Comment: what code is in the `checklength()`

Comment: checklength() checks whether the user pressed ctrl+v

Comment: post the code of checklength

Comment: agree, post code. test here http://jsfiddle.net/4PfX6/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<b>Name</b>
<input type="text" id="txtname" />

$("#txtname").bind('paste', function (e) {
    setTimeout(function (e) {
   var x=$("#txtname").val().length;
        alert(x);
        }, 100);

});
```

check the jsfiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/arunberti/34VCF/